# Deploy Ruby on Rails com Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deploy, capistrano

Ao executar o *deploy* tenho o seguinte erro: `Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing 'secret_token' and 'secret_key_bas' for 'production' environment, set these values in 'config/secrets.yml`

Já fiz as configurações necessárias mas não consigo encontrar o problema.

Tenho o `set :linked_files, ["#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]` no meu `config/deploy.rb`.

Estou usando o plugin `capistrano-secrets-yml` para colocar o meu *secrets.yml* no local correto:

```
l shared/config/secrets.yml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myiser 63 Aug  4 10:44 shared/config/secrets.yml -> /home/myuser/apps/myapp/shared/config/secrets.yml
```

E também exportei o secret da em meu `.bashrc` -> `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=MY_SECRET`

E o *secrets.yml` utiliza esta variável:

```
production:
    secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

O que poderia estar errado?

Comment: Ja verificou se o <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %> está retornando nulo?

Comment: Abri on console em meu server `rails c` e ao digitar `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']` está retornando o *secret* corretamente. Será que não falta alguma configuração no *capistrano* em que ele não está conseguindo pegar essa variável?

Comment: Descobri o problema, o `<%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>` no *secrets.yml* não funciona, se eu colocar o *hash* na mão funciona corretamente, mas como pegar das variáveis de ambiente.

Comment: Quase tinha falado isso kkkkk, boa, tirei uma das minhas dúvidas também

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver este problema adicionando a gem [dotEnv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). Adicione a gem em seu Gemfile, no grupo de desenvolvimento.

Rode o bundle; e pronto! Basta criar um arquivo `.env` na raiz do seu projeto e passar as variáveis de ambiente que deseja utilizar. Por exemplo:

```
secret_key_base= "234df4r3j43r49..."
```

E lá nos arquivos do Rails você usa `ENV['secret_key_base']`